# wso2 api manager with azure ad as OAuth provider

Tags: azure-active-directory, wso2-api-manager

We have a requirement to configure WSO2 api manager with Azure AD as OAuth provider. We do not intend to use the out-of-the box OAuth provider in WSO2 api platform. All other parts of API manager will be leveraged ( publisher, store, gateway). Below given is the scenario

1. A mobile app is the client for APIs
2. User authentication from the app is done via Azure Ad
3. Azure AD provides a token back after successful authentication
4. Mobile app  invokes the API  ( via wso2 api gateway) using the token issued by Azure Ad.
5. API gateway verifies the validity of the token and allows the api invocation if it is valid

What is the best way to achieve this? Any input is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve your use case by configuring a 3rd part key manager
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+a+Third-Party+Key+Manager